# What happened to the basis of 1⊗1/2 when we write 1/2⊗1?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

I am doing an exercise of calculating the Clebsch-Gordan (CG) coefficient of $\frac{1}{2}\otimes 1 =\frac{3}{2} \oplus \frac{1}{2}$. Without realizing that the general convention is to have $j_1 > j_2$, I chose $|\frac{1}{2},1\rangle$ instead of $|1,\frac{1}{2}\rangle$.

Evaluating $\bf{|J,M\rangle}$ for $\bf{|\frac{3}{2},M\rangle}$ wasn't difficult, but the problem arise when I was trying to evaluate $\bf{|\frac{1}{2},M\rangle}$ by using the orthogonality properties and taking the inner product with $\bf{|\frac{3}{2},M\rangle}$.

While evaluating ${\bf{|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle}} = \alpha|\frac{1}{2},0\rangle +\beta|-\frac{1}{2},1\rangle$, after taking inner product with ${\bf{|\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle}} = \sqrt\frac{2}{3}|\frac{1}{2},0\rangle +\sqrt\frac{1}{3}|-\frac{1}{2},1\rangle$, and solving for the unknowns yield $\alpha = \pm\sqrt\frac{1}{3}$ and $\beta = \mp\sqrt\frac{2}{3}$.

Following the phase convention of $\langle j_1,j_2;j_1,(j-j_1)|j,j\rangle $, I found that to obey such convention, I need to have

> ${\bf{|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle}} = \sqrt\frac{1}{3}|\frac{1}{2},0\rangle -\sqrt\frac{2}{3}|-\frac{1}{2},1\rangle$ (my answer)

but the standard CG table reads:

> ${\bf{|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle}} = -\sqrt\frac{1}{3}|0,\frac{1}{2}\rangle +\sqrt\frac{2}{3}|-1,\frac{1}{2}\rangle$

which is just $(-1)$ off the given answer. So it makes me wonder if the observation of:

> $|0, \frac{1}{2}\rangle = -|\frac{1}{2},0\rangle$

or more generally,

> $|j_1m_1\rangle \otimes |j_2m_2\rangle  = - |j_2m_2\rangle \otimes |j_1m_1\rangle  $

holds every time? I saw a statement of $ V\otimes W \cong W\otimes V$ but not sure how the basis in these two spaces change.

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes I know that there will be 6 bases in total. But I am asking what will be the change in the basis of 1⊗1/2 if we write 1/2⊗1 instead? And can I know what is a  "dimensionality-of-multiplets notation"? Any example/link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, correct your mistake, to
$\frac{1}{2}\otimes 1 =\frac{3}{2} \oplus \frac{1}{2}$. In my comment, I suggested it is impossible to make it, if only you use the dimensionality of the multiplets, instead of the spin, to label them, in boldface, so ${\mathbf 2} \otimes {\mathbf 3}  ={\mathbf 4} \oplus {\mathbf 2}$.  The tensor factors themselves do not have an intrinsic order. It's what you choose to do with them!

Specifically, let's inspect [this](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-clebsch-gordan-coefs.pdf), and in particular the orthogonal matrix for the ${\mathbf 2}$ you are inspecting. Note the off-diagonal terms must have minus signs for the matrix to be orthogonal, and the C-S condition $\langle j_1,j_1~~j_2,(J-j_1)|J,J\rangle >0 $ in the standard convention, *not your* language, heavily discriminates for the first factor. So changing the order of rows will have to flip relative signs in the two orderings, according to the identity,
$$
\langle j_1~m_1~~ j_2~m_2|JM\rangle = (-)^{J-j_1-j_2} \langle j_2~m_2~~ j_1~m_1|JM\rangle,
$$
with the exponent being -1 for your Clebsches of interest.

Specifically,
$$
\langle 1~0~~ 1/2~1/2 |\tfrac{1}{2} ~ \tfrac{1}{2}  \rangle = -\sqrt{1/3}, \\
\langle 1~1 ~~1/2 ~ -\!1/2  |\tfrac{1}{2} ~ \tfrac{1}{2}  \rangle  = \sqrt{2/3} , ~~~~~*  \\
\langle 1/2~1/2 ~~ 1~0  |\tfrac{1}{2} ~ \tfrac{1}{2}  \rangle = \sqrt{1/3} ,~~~~~*   \\
\langle 1/2 ~ -\!1/2 ~~ 1~1 |\tfrac{1}{2} ~ \tfrac{1}{2}  \rangle=-\sqrt{2/3}  ,
$$
where the * s indicate the maximal states forced to be positive by the C-S condition. The point is the symmetry condition relates them all properly. Inspection of the entire Clebsch matrix makes it inevitable.

[image]
[image]