# Operator acting on tensor product of states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, representation-theory

Working with $SU(2)$, from Clebsch-Gordan coefficient tables I have for example:
$$|j=3/2, m=3/2\rangle \;= |1, 1\rangle \otimes |1/2, 1/2\rangle
$$

How can I write $\hat{O}|j=3/2, m=3/2\rangle$ in terms of $|1, 1 \rangle \otimes| 1/2, 1/2\rangle$ ?

My guess would be something like:
$$\hat{O}|j=3/2, m=3/2\rangle = (\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{O} + \hat{O} \otimes \mathbb{1})|1, 1 \rangle\otimes |1/2, 1/2\rangle
$$

Is this correct? Is this a valid question in the first place, or is such an operation undefined?

Comment: Your notation is highly unconventional... indeed, freaky. There is no general recipe for a generic operator $\hat O$; if it were an angular momentum component, your expression would be right. If a Casimir invariant, very wrong.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632973/what-does-the-notation-frac12-otimes-frac12-1-oplus-0-mean-exact) and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/629889/66086).

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is unconventional, but I'll humor you,
$$|3/2,3/2\rangle = |1, 1\rangle \otimes |1/2, 1/2\rangle.
$$
In simpler, intuitive notation, (vectors of the right space into vector components of the left one), this is just
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\oplus\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} ,
$$
reminding you of the "accidental" Clebsches being 1 and 0 respectively for the reduced spin subspaces. Had you chosen *m=1/2* on the left, life would have been dramatically different, since the vector spaces on either side are really 6-dimensional, **3/2 ⊕ 1/2 = 1 ⊗ 1/2** . Normally, you go from the r.h.side to the l.h.side which is special in your case.

But since you are asking for your extreme, unrepresentative, example, for *linear* angular-momentum operators, such as $\hat j_0, \hat j_{\pm}$, you'd have, indeed, in this case  (only),
$$
\Delta(\hat j_i)= (\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{j_i} + \hat{j_i} \otimes \mathbb{1}),
$$
so
$$\hat{j_i}|3/2, 3/2\rangle = (\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{j_i} + \hat{j_i} \otimes \mathbb{1})(|1, 1\rangle \otimes |1/2, 1/2\rangle ).
$$
In a less sadistic , conventional, notation, e.g. for $\hat j_0$,
$$
(3/2)\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\oplus\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes (1/2)\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} =
(3/2) \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Although correct, this is somewhat misleading, since it does not dramatize the need for Clebsching: basis changes on the left to disentangle the invariant subspaces.

And likewise for the other two *su(2)* generators. Of course, for $\hat j_+$ on the l.h.side and $\Delta(\hat j_+)$ on the r.h.side you get 0. For  $\Delta(\hat j_-)$,
$$
\sqrt{3/2}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\oplus\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes (1/\sqrt{2})\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}  .
$$
On the r.h.side you got $(0, 1/\sqrt{2}, 1,0,0, 0)^T$, which reduced to the l.h.side in a different (Clebsched) basis.

***However***, as emphasized in a [linked answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/632993/66086), if the operator $\hat O$ is a Casimir invariant, instead, the quadratic in generators labelling the representation (spin), then the above formula fails, dramatically. You must square the *Δ*s of each generator, and sum them together, giving you a more elaborate expression, since there are cross terms. Your notation would not serve you then. To preserve your sanity, I'd write the corresponding conventional expression,
$$
(\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{j_i} + \hat{j_i} \otimes \mathbb{1})(\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{j_i} + \hat{j_i} \otimes \mathbb{1})\left (\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\otimes \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right ) 
$$
on the right, which would [Clebsch](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629647/what-happened-to-the-basis-of-1%E2%8A%971-2-when-we-write-1-2%E2%8A%971/629889#629889), on the left, to 15/4 acting on  *any* quartet (any spin 3/2 state), and 3/4 on the doublet (but not the trivial null spin 1/2 state here).

---

*In undergraduate addition-of-angular-momentum language*:

$$
|3/2 ~ 3/2\rangle = |1 1;1/2 1/2\rangle \\
\hat {j}_0: \qquad 3/2~ |3/2 ~ 3/2\rangle =(1+1/2) |1 ~1;1/2~ 1/2\rangle \\
\hat {j}_+:\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad 0=0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\\
\hat{ j}_-: ~~ \sqrt{3/2}~ |3/2 ~ 1/2\rangle =  |1 ~0;1/2 ~1/2\rangle +(1/\sqrt{2}) |1 ~1;1/2 ~-1/2\rangle \\
  \hat {j}^2: \qquad 15/4 ~ |3/2 ~ 3/2\rangle =( 15/4) |1 ~1;1/2 ~1/2\rangle
. $$